# Latin to deduct or withhold taxes

Tags: sentence-translation

What is the correct way to say the following in Latin:

> "when in doubt, withhold tax"
>
> (or "when in doubt, deduct tax")

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you specify the context? A "withholding" is not the same as a "deduction."

Answer (score 2):

Whichever the English version of the two that you propose, *quandoque dubium sit, tributum retine* should (if you'll forgive the pun) fill the bill : literally, 'whenever there may be doubt, retain the tax'.